# Query posts only without featured image

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

want to query 100 posts, but only those which do not have a featured image attached. I am using meta_key method for this with WP_Query as such:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'  => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
    )
);
```

But Not work with me

Any help ?

Comment: Please explain *But Not work with me*

Comment: my code its not show me any result

Comment: use if statement like this `if(!has_post_thumbnail())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code , its working for me

```
value=>'?'
```

because(value was required for `NOT EXISTS` comparisons to work correctly prior to 3.9. You had to supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or `NULL` will NOT work. However, any other string will do the trick and will NOT show up in your SQL when using `NOT EXISTS`.)

For more information about `value=>?` please refer [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'  => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 100,
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '?',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
     )
  ),
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'value' => '?' doesn't make sense in this context:

In this code, even if 'value' is set, it's actually ignored by WordPress when using 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'. In other words, WordPress doesn't take into account the value provided for the 'value' key when it checks for the existence or non-existence of a meta key.

In conclusion, while this code might work in practice (since 'value' is ignored), my example is more precise and clear. It's better to use my example to avoid any potential confusion.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_status'   => array('publish', 'draft', 'pending'),
    'meta_query'    => array(
       array(
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
       )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```